# Is there a plugin that requires login to view Frontend WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins

We are creating a multi-vendor marketplace, we need our first vendors only to view the site and upload products to it before we launch it for the public to view. The thing is most plugins like Force Login, takes them to the WP-Admin. We don't want them to see the admin page, just only see the site as a front-end user with no access to see the backend.

Simply > Type Url > Get to a login page Landing Page (like how when you log into FB web there's a login page with info about FB) > Vendors Only can Log in a view the FRONT END only site > When time to launch, login in page comes down and visitors all can view it.

Answer (score 0):

Its default feature of wordpress. do hire some developer if you are not aware of base functionalities.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm thinking. Thank you!